# ASIO: What is the difference between a loopback address and a "local service binding"?

Tags: c++, networking, boost-asio

I am trying to get into ASIO and I have been reading the docs and came across this:

https://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.24.0/doc/asio/reference/ip__basic_resolver/resolve/overload5.html

> If an empty string and the passive flag has been specified, the
> resolved endpoints are suitable for local service binding. If an empty
> string and passive is not specified, the resolved endpoints will use
> the loopback address.

I am not well versed with networking stuff, so I tried to find out what the difference between these two is (loopback and local service binding), but none of the sources I found really gave a good explanation to what these two things are.

Both of the options are just going to use ports on the local machine as far as I know, so what's the difference? Which one should I use if I intend to use ASIO to just establish connections between C++ programs that all run on the same machine?

Answer (score 0):

The wording seems curious. However we can "just try" it:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/90cfafab5d7899d3)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using namespace boost::asio;
    io_context ioc;
    ip::tcp::resolver r(ioc);

    auto report = [](auto results) {
        std::cout << "---\n";
        for (auto el : results)
            std::cout << std::quoted(el.host_name()) << "+"
                      << std::quoted(el.service_name()) << " -> "
                      << el.endpoint() << "\n";
    };

    report(r.resolve("", "finger", ip::resolver_base::flags::passive));
    report(r.resolve("", "finger"));
}
```

Printing

```
---
""+"finger" -> 0.0.0.0:79
""+"finger" -> [::]:79
---
""+"finger" -> [::1]:79
""+"finger" -> 127.0.0.1:79
```

Clearly, specifying `passive` leads to "unbound" interface in the endpoint, whereas the default result binds to the explicit address of the loopback adapter.

I think the main difference here would be when you bind a listening port to such an endpoint.